# Run SQL PLUS one by one in batch file

Tags: batch-file, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have some `sql` files in a directory and I want to run the `sql` file using `sql plus` using my batch file coding.

My code looks like below.

```
start sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%GIName% "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql" 
start sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%CIName% "@%~dp0SQL\DBLINK\CIDBLINK.sql" '''%MDBName%'''
start sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%CSName% "@%~dp0SQL\DBLINK\CUDBLINK.sql" '''%MDBName%'''
start sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%PIName% "@%~dp0SQL\DBLINK\PIDBLINK.sql" '''%MDBName%'''
start sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%PUName% "@%~dp0SQL\DBLINK\PUDBLINK.sql" '''%GIName%'''
```

I want to run the above command one after another rather running all in parallel since each `sql` is depend on another one.

Looking forward your help.

Comment: Have you tried using the `/wait` parameter of start? I'd try that or not use start at all.

Comment: Don't use `start` - call sqlplus directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply use "start /wait", OR use "call " and put each single script execution in its own batch file which calculates exit code and returns a 0, 1, or error code .

This script proves it works:

```
@echo off
call :timepause 3
call :timepause 3
call :timepause 3
echo %errorlevel%
call :rerror 2
echo %errorlevel%
goto :end
:timepause num
echo timeout for %1 seconds...
ping -n %1 -w 1000 127.1 >NUL
exit /b 0
:rerror num
echo error after %1 seconds...
ping -n %1 -w 1000 127.1 >NUL
exit /b 1
:end
pause
```

Comment: Thanks. I dont want to create more bat files and call it. I will try using start/wait in each line above. But my question is will it work the same way of "call"

Comment: By using separate batch files you could have more fine grained control of what exit code returns.  using 'start' you just accept the default exit code that the program returns (a  0 or 1 ).  This matters a lot when you run your script on Jenkins but not so much otherwise.

Comment: I tried but no luck.. still its running in parallel. I created a seperate batch file to call and run sql queries after my main sql runs 'start sqlplus %DBUName%/%DBPwd%@%GISName% "@%~dp0SQL\SetUp\SETUP.sql" CALL "%~dp0Config\DBLINK.bat" %DBUName% %DBPwd% %GISName%'

Comment: Ok, I edited my question with proof that it will work.